# directshow, how to know if a filter is in use by another application

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I have a source filter that cannot be used in two applications at the same time.
Is there a way to know if the filter is in use by another application?
I am able to add the filter to the graph, connect it, but the exception rises when I do "run graph." The application exits with a generic "Unknown error". I use DirectShowLibNET.
I want to show a specific error like "Filter in use".

Comment: Have you written this source filter yourself? In C++ or C#? Is it using the GSSF framework provided by DirectShow.NET?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your filter, you can create a named memory mapped file, shared by the processes, and make it visible if there is any instance running in another application. Otherwise, there is no way to find out.